# Why is my transistor getting very hot when controlling a 12V peristalic pump?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, transistor

I have followed this tutorial:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Automatically-water-your-small-indoor-plant-using-/?ALLSTEPS

Every time i try to run my circuit, My transistor gets very hot and breaks.

I have exactly the same parts as the tutorial. I have also tested the circuit with 3.3V Power supply and a diode instead of an engine, this works.

I am super thankfull for any answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks?" Can you please add more information to your post? Thanks!

Comment: I would be surprised if it worked. As far as I can tell (from the poor instructions) he is connecting the base directly to the Arduino pin. This would overload the chip, although the inbuilt current limiter would protect it. I certainly wouldn't use a PN2222 to switch 300mA.

Comment: As @Milliways suggested, you need to add a resistor between the arduino pin and the transistor. Around 1k will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Measure the Current through the motor, the PN2222 can pass a maximum of 600mA.
I would guess that just over half an amp would be enough for the motor but you can check what you motor is trying to pull by connecting it to 12 V direct and measure the supply current.
The only thing that will make the transistor hot is excess current